# re-arrange php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array

```
Array ( [1] => Vice President [3] => Secretary [5] => Treasurer )
```

I want make it change to

```
Array ( [0] => Vice President [1] => Secretary [2] => Treasurer )
```

I have try us php for loop function

```
$ub_new_arr_sort = array();
for($i3 = 0; $i3 < count($ub_new_arr); $i3++){
$ub_new_arr_sort[] = $ub_new_arr[$i3];
}
```

but seem like not work at all, any idea?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: For the record, "your" way did not work because you're iterating over the fictional indexes `0..2`. However, the array used the indexes `1`, `3`, and `5`. The `foreach` construct would have [worked](http://www.ideone.com/IzTkT), although @Francois Deschenes' answer is more elegant, IMO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`array_values`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: If you found this was the best solution be sure to mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach instead of for to be 'key independant':

```
foreach($oldarray as $position){
    $newArray[] = $position;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: @wyman Just so that you understood what was wrong in your code: your `for` was looping from 0 to `count()`, so the values were `0,1,2` while keys actually are `1,3,5`. In fact PHP was generating E_NOTICEs when you tried to read non-existent keys 0 and 2. Always keep `error_reporting=E_ALL|E_STRICT` in php.ini on your development machine, it will prevent you from making obvious bugs.